# Changing existing GL texture size and pixel data

Tags: java, lwjgl

To make things short, a GL texture is allocated and created prior to my code running (I cannot prevent the first texture from being created, but I know the GL id that it is attached to). I need to redefine that existing texture using a buffered image that is twice the size of the old image. Does anybody know how to approach doing something like this? Based on some Google searches, it would look like I need to use ***glTexSubImage2D***, but I'm not sure how.
Any help on the matter would be useful, Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with calling `glTexImage2D()` with your new size/data?

Comment: If you have access to modern OpenGL, use `glTexStorage` otherwise follow the Reto's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you cannot replace in-place the texture, you have to allocate a new texture and on the next rendering, you will have to remap the texture index when you do the rendering.

The OpenGL is to high level to have access to previous textures memory and edit it.

There is a tutorial to change on the same shape a specific texture:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/playing_avi_files_in_opengl/23001/